# Give access to azure data explorer dashboard

Tags: permissions, azure, azure-activedirectory

I have been added as a user on someone else's Azure subscription, and have created a dashboard on https://dataexplorer.azure.com/.

I now want to give the owner of the domain access to that dashboard.

I have so far taken the following steps:

1. In Azure Portal, I have gone to the Azure Data Explorer Cluster -> Database -> Select the database -> Permissions. The user is a Database Admin.
2. In Azure Data Explorer, I have run `.show database dbName principals` to confirm that the user is there. They are, twice - as "Cluster AllDatabasesAdmin" and "Database dbName Admin". Both times, their user shows up in the form `User Name (upn: user_name.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@msdnusernameco.onmicrosoft.com)`
3. In Azure Data Explorer, I have gone to the dashboard -> Share -> Manage Permissions. I have added the same user (again, they show up with #EXT# in the middle)
4. I have sent the link to the user, who says they do not have access to the dashboard.

Can anyone advise on the next steps for troubleshooting?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No, sorry, not yet! I don't have the time to investigate more at the moment, but feel free to put a bounty on the question if you are interested in seeing an answer